# why is my dictionary list not importing to another module

Tags: python, list

i am doing a category module and a shopping cart module. i created an empty dictionary in category module but my category module's data isn't importing into my ShoppingCart module. Specifically the GetList function which is to import an empty dictionary.

## category.py

```
def list1():
    global getList
    getList = []

    try:
        f = open("userItem.txt", "r")
        for line in f:
            getList.append(line.strip())
            f.close()
    except:
        pass


def saveList():  # saving data in getList
    with open("userItem.txt") as infile:
        item = txt.load(infile)  # item list
    return item


def addItem():
    list1()
    for item in getList:
        if len(item) > 0:
            getList.append(item)
            saveList()
            category()
        else:
            category()


def category():
    item = "HP Printer 2529 Deskjet Ink Advantage Home Use Printer 3 in 1"
    quantity_1 = float(
        input("ENTER NUMBER OF QUANTITY: ")
    )
    quan_price = quantity_1 * 299.00
    print(f"\nTotal price: RM {quan_price}")
    condition = input(
        "are you sure you want to buy? "
    )
    if condition == "yes":
        addItem()
    else:
        category()
```

## shoppingCart.py

```
def shoppingCart():
    print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    print('          SHOPPING CART         ')
    print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    print('\nYou got ', len(getList),'items.\n')
```

Comment: NameError: name 'getList' is not defined

Comment: Why _would_ it? There's no `import` statement in the shopping list file at all...

Comment: In Python, every "global" identifier is defined in the module where it is specified, and is not available to other modules, unless properly [imported](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're not importing anything from `category.py` in your `shoppingCart.py`.

Adding

```
from category import getList
```

to the shopping cart file would be a start.